# "Anonymous" appears in the top-left corner of my Wordpress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, anonymous

For my web page [here](http://sagecanada.com/), the Wordpress pages keep on showing the word "anonymous" in the top-left corner.

I have tried disabling all of the plugins but that didn't affect it. I also changed the theme and it disappeared so I'm certain it's a theme problem.

I've disabled javascript to see if it was a conflict there but it didn't help the situation. I'm wondering if anybody else has this problem with any of their themes as I tried searching but I didn't see any results.

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Post your themes code...

Comment: double check index.php , it might be there

Comment: It shows up in the HTML markup, so it's no Javascript issue. And the output is right at the beginning, even before the doctype, so this is not going through any of the Wordpress filters and templates, but must be something like an `echo` early on in the theme files. Possibly `functions.php`, but I'm guessing. Yes, post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on where it is in the HTML and the fact that you narrowed it down to a theme issue, have a look in the offending theme's `header.php` file. If there's a rogue `echo` outputting the logged-in user's name or something, I'd say you've found it.

Comment: [Code for Header.php](http://www.pastie.org/private/izutt6rt7wddzzrqkugc5a)

[Code for Index.php](http://www.pastie.org/private/uopvjgum1baf1lslim2ca)

Comment: I cannot find anything broken in these two files. However, it looks like this is a commercial theme from Premiumpress.com, which you probably don't have the right to publish here completely for analysis. Why don't you turn to the company for support instead?